# Flutter - how to remove default padding (48 px as per doc) from widgets (IconButton, CheckBox, FlatButton)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, padding, flutter-widget

I am facing a problem with the default padding of the widgets (IconButton, CheckBox, FlatButton). I have searched a lot for this concern but with no success.

[image]

In the above image, the outer blue rect is the actual size of these widgets and I have to remove that space.

```
Checkbox(
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _rememberMeFlag = !_rememberMeFlag;
            });
          },
          value: _rememberMeFlag,
          activeColor: const Color(0xff00bbff),
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        )
```

and below is the widget code for hide/show widget icon:

```
new Container(
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Password",
              suffixIcon: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.zero,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    hidePassword ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                    size: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 0.0, top: 6.0, bottom: 6.0, right: 0.0),
            ),
            obscureText: !hidePassword,
            maxLength: 20,
          ),
        )
```

I have tried to set the container size too but no luck. Also tried the padding properties of the widgets but with no success.

Is there any way to remove this extra spacing from these widgets?

Comment: why dont you use standard [CheckboxListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html)?

Comment: @pskink it is causing more spacing then required one. Project owner is asking us to reduce that space.

Comment: best way use this

    Checkbox(
    .
    .
    .
    visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                      horizontal: VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
                      vertical: VisualDensity.minimumDensity),
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    )

Answer (score 172):

wrap your `CheckBox` inside `SizedBox` will resize the padding of the check box

```
  SizedBox(
    height: 24.0,
    width: 24.0,
    child: Checkbox(...),
 )
```

Comment: Simple yet effective. Additional plus for using standard widgets without relying on method overriding.

Comment: Not working for me with a CheckboxListTile, touch space area is not changing and it is overlapping. I have 3 CheckboxListTile, if set height on SizedBox it looks as I want but when tap on one check box other activates.

Comment: @Inmer FYI CheckboxistTile having touch in the entire tile I guess, if you want to customize the touch space and all, you have to create your own tile with a row.

Comment: working even for TabBar unwanted top|bottom Tab padings

Comment: @AfinasEM Works for me fine, but could you please explain why it is working?

Comment: @JonasDeichelmann the `SizedBox` will make its child re-size to the same given to it.

Answer (score 42):

There are three options:

1.

```dart
 // or Checkbox()
Radio( 
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
)
```

2. 

```dart
 // or Checkbox()
Radio(
    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),
)
```

3. 

```dart
SizedBox(
    height: 20, 
    width: 20, 
 // or Checkbox()
    child: Radio()
    )
```

Comment: Great short solution.!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 34):

EDIT

Set the value of ***materialTapTargetSize*** to **MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap**

```
Checkbox(
   materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    ...
 )
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve this by customising the Checkbox widget.

1. Create a CustomCheckbox using the exact code from
   *flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/checkbox.dart*.
2. Add a new field to your CustomCheckbox widget

   ```
        final bool useTapTarget;
   ```
3. Make sure to add the new field to your constructor with it default
   value set to true.

   ```
        this.useTapTarget = true
   ```
4. Modify the build method in the *_CheckboxState* method. Add this
   block of code above the return call.

   ```
        Size noTapTargetSize = Size(CustomCheckbox.width, 
        CustomCheckbox.width);
        final BoxConstraints additionalConstraints = 
        BoxConstraints.tight(widget
           .useTapTarget? size : noTapTargetSize);
   ```
5. Finally, use your CustomCheckbox widget in your code, and set your
   custom field to false to remove material padding. example

   ```
   Container(
           margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
           child:CustomCheckbox(
               value: _checked,
               onChanged: _onCheckBoxChange,
               useTapTarget: false,
               activeColor: Colors.teal),
         )
   ```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

The default dimensions of `Checkbox` widget is 48x48. So, as per the above answer, if we wrap `Checkbox` inside `SizedBox` then the white spacing reduces. I tried with 24x24 and all the spacing was gone.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 24.0,
  height: 24.0,
  child: Checkbox(),
```

After this, I wrapped `SizedBox` inside the `Padding` widget to give any side of spacing I want.

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 24.0,
    height: 24.0,
    child: Checkbox(),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 6):

For those looking for copy and paste ;), here is what I use

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NoPaddingCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isMarked;
  final Function(bool newValue) onChange;
  final double size;

  NoPaddingCheckbox({
    @required this.isMarked,
    @required this.onChange,
    this.size = 24,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: size, maxWidth: size),
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
        child: Icon(_getIconData(), size: size),
        onPressed: () => onChange(!isMarked),
      ),
    );
  }

  IconData _getIconData() {
    if (isMarked) {
      return Icons.check_box;
    }

    return Icons.check_box_outline_blank;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Wrap(
    children: <Widget>[
        Text('radio'),
        Radio(
            groupValue: _character,
            onChanged: (value){},
            materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        )
    ],
    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
),
```

this removes lots of spaces

Answer (score 2):

If you want the padding removed because it is causing the control to be too far to the right or too far down (I wanted the control to be perfectly left aligned), you could wrap it in a [TransForm.translate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.translate.html).

```
Transform.translate(
  offset: const Offset(-24, 0),
  child: Checkbox(...),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

**this is for particular for Checkbox**

assign following property for remove padding

**materialTapTargetSize:MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap**,

show code

```
 Checkbox(
       materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
           value: agreeForTC, // bool value 
                          onChanged: (bool? update) {
                            setState(() => agreeForTC = update!); // update bool
                            debugPrint('agreeForTC : $agreeForTC');
                        },
           )
```

but this will still have some required padding and remove this just wrap Checkbox in SizeBox and give width and height

```
   SizedBox(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        child: Checkbox(
                          materialTapTargetSize:
                              MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                       
                          value: agreeForTC,
                          onChanged: (bool? update) {
                            setState(() => agreeForTC = update!);
                            debugPrint('agreeForTC : $agreeForTC');
           },
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method I found is to create your version of the widget usually by combining `GestureDetector` Widget with something. For example, here's a version of the `IconButton` which doesn't have the default Material Design padding:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    //do stuff here
  },
  child: Icon(
    Icons.icon_choice
  ),
)
```

Comment: This will not support default checkbox animations

Comment: Don´t reivent the wheel is a good principle that should be followed

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing things by opening `IconButton` class by clicking on `IconButton` while pressing `ctrl` in windows. Then you will find a variable `Padding = EdgeConsts.all(8.0)` . Keep changing it and play with it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by customising the Checkbox widget's **_outerRectAt** method:

```
RRect _outerRectAt(Offset origin, double t) {
    final double inset = 1.0 - (t - 0.5).abs() * 2.0;
    final double size = _kEdgeSize - inset * _kStrokeWidth;
    //final Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(origin.dx + inset, origin.dy + inset, size, size); //ORIGINAL
    final Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, origin.dy + inset, size, size); //CUSTOM
    return RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, _kEdgeRadius);
}
```

With this modification the result is :

[image]

Last, but not least, you need to change the **_drawCheck** method like this :

```
void _drawCheck(Canvas canvas, Offset origin, double t, Paint paint) {
    assert(t >= 0.0 && t <= 1.0);
    // As t goes from 0.0 to 1.0, animate the two check mark strokes from the
    // short side to the long side.
    final Path path = Path();
    const Offset start = Offset(_kEdgeSize * 0.15, _kEdgeSize * 0.45);
    const Offset mid = Offset(_kEdgeSize * 0.4, _kEdgeSize * 0.7);
    const Offset end = Offset(_kEdgeSize * 0.85, _kEdgeSize * 0.25);
    if (t < 0.5) {
        final double strokeT = t * 2.0;
        final Offset drawMid = Offset.lerp(start, mid, strokeT);

        //NEW
        path.moveTo(0 + start.dx, origin.dy + start.dy);
        path.lineTo(0 + drawMid.dx, origin.dy + drawMid.dy);

        //OLD
        /*path.moveTo(origin.dx + start.dx, origin.dy + start.dy);
        path.lineTo(origin.dx + drawMid.dx, origin.dy + drawMid.dy);*/
    } else {
        final double strokeT = (t - 0.5) * 2.0;
        final Offset drawEnd = Offset.lerp(mid, end, strokeT);

        //NEW
        path.moveTo(0 + start.dx, origin.dy + start.dy);
        path.lineTo(0 + mid.dx, origin.dy + mid.dy);
        path.lineTo(0 + drawEnd.dx, origin.dy + drawEnd.dy);

        //OLD
        /*path.moveTo(origin.dx + start.dx, origin.dy + start.dy);
        path.lineTo(origin.dx + mid.dx, origin.dy + mid.dy);
        path.lineTo(origin.dx + drawEnd.dx, origin.dy + drawEnd.dy);*/
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code (Also solves circular tap effect's size):**

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var size = 20.0; // Your desired size.
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: Size.fromRadius(size / 2),
        child: IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          splashRadius: size,
          iconSize: size,
          icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Checkbox instead of CheckboxListTile and wrap CheckBox with Transform.scale,

```
 Transform.scale(
         scale: 1.2,
         child: Checkbox(), 
          )
```